# Change ListBox selected item on finger tap, not on finger release

Tags: windows-phone-7

The Windows Phone `ListBox` control changes the selected item when the user releases the finger after having tapped the item. I would like the selected item to change as soon as the user taps the item, without waiting the finger to be released. Is there any way to achieve this?

Actually what I want to do is to handle the ListBox "Hold" event to do something on the selected item. Currently, two taps are needed (one short tap for selecting the item, and another one for the hold behavior), and I would like one tap to be enough bor both changing the selected item, and the hold behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Hold` gesture instead.

If you need a context menu, use the `ContextMenu` from the [Silverlight Toolkit].

Comment: If you're on WP7.5 you should really be using the Silverlight Hold event and avoiding the GestureListener. That avoid the need to load the XNA libraries that GestureListener needs.

Comment: I couldn't remember if the Hold gesture was implemented for the ListBoxItem ;-)

Comment: Thank you but I am already controlling the Hold event. What I want is to have current item changed + hold event with just one finger tap, now I need two.

Comment: No? You already know what item you selected with the Hold event. You don't need more information than that.